# AlertDialog crashes when i click on Preference

Tags: java, android, xml, dialog

i have a problem. I've created a class called Brightness for manage the brightness of the screen by a SeekBar in a Dialog. This is the class.

```
public class Brightness extends Activity{

    private SeekBar brightbar;
    private int brightness;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private ContentResolver cResolver;
    private Window window;
    TextView txtPerc;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ShowDialog();

    }


    public void ShowDialog() {

    final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View Viewlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_brightness, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_dialog));  

        popDialog.setTitle("Set brightness");
        popDialog.setView(Viewlayout);

    brightbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.brightbar);
    txtPerc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
    cResolver = getContentResolver();
    window = getWindow();
    brightbar.setMax(255);
    brightbar.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);

    brightbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.brightbar);
    txtPerc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPercentage);
    cResolver = getContentResolver();
    window = getWindow();
    brightbar.setMax(255);
    brightbar.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);

    try
    {
        brightness = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
        float perc = (brightness /(float)255)*100;
        txtPerc.setText((int)perc +" %");
    }
    catch (SettingNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.e("Error", "Cannot access system brightness");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    brightbar.setProgress(brightness);
    brightbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
            LayoutParams layoutpars = window.getAttributes();
            layoutpars.screenBrightness = brightness / (float)255;
            window.setAttributes(layoutpars);
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {

        }

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {


                brightness = progress;

                float perc = (brightness /(float)255)*100;
                txtPerc.setText((int)perc +" %");
        }
    });     

    popDialog.setNeutralButton("Close",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            });

    popDialog.create();
    popDialog.show();

}
}
```

In another class, a PreferenceActivity, I have a preference that says "Brightness". I would like clicking on this would open the Preference Dialog and then I put this code.

```
Preference brigh;
brigh = (Preference) this.findPreference("brightness_pref");

brigh.setOnPreferenceClickListener( new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

    Brightness brightness = new Brightness();
        brightness.ShowDialog();

        return true;

    }
});
```

But when I run the application and I click on the Preference, crashes. This is the logcat

> 11-10 18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-10
>   18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-10 18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:146)
>   11-10 18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:103)
>   11-10 18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143) 11-10
>   18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at
>   android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.(AlertDialog.java:360) 11-10
>   18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at
>   com.simonedev.androtools.Brightness.ShowDialog(Brightness.java:39)
>   11-10 18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   com.simonedev.androtools.Impostazioni$1.onPreferenceClick(Settings.java:48)
>   11-10 18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:952) 11-10
>   18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at
>   android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:215)
>   11-10 18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:297)
>   11-10 18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
>   11-10 18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
>   11-10 18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463) 11-10
>   18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 11-10
>   18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 11-10
>   18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-10 18:23:34.955:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289) 11-10
>   18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-10
>   18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 11-10 18:23:34.955:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
>   11-10 18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555) 11-10
>   18:23:34.955: E/AndroidRuntime(945):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I can not understand how to solve. Can you kindly help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
because of you are not start activity with intent. if you want show only AlertDialog you can use in in PreferenceActivity.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: where did you create an instance from `Brightness` class? I mean you are calling a method of `Brightness` activity from another that use `AlertDialog`.

Comment: The class from which call ShowDialog is a PreferenceActivity that contains no AlertDialog, but the purpose is to bring up the Dialog from method ShowDialog (class Brightness)